# "your own hard-earn reputation" should be "your own hard-earned reputation" on the Help Center Reputation & Privileges page

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

"hard-earn" should be "hard-earned", in the second paragraph on [the new Reputation & Privileges help page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/bounty).

The corrected complete sentence would then be

Slice off anywhere from +50 to +500 of your own hard-earned reputation, and [attach it to any question as a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties).

Comment: Did atwood ever tweet about beating people to death with a giant `ed` for posts about subject-verb agreement???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sentence has been fixed now.

Comment: Missed a great opportunity for "That sentence has been fix now."

Comment: @JoshDM *Resists temptation to make that edit...*